# Toolbar back button replaced for default icon for a half second when clicking on it

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

i'm trying to replace default back button icon on toolbar like this:

```
toolbar.navigationIcon = R.drawable.lalala
```

it's fine, and it's working. But, when i'm trying to click back button, for a half second i can see default icon instead of mine. What i can do wrong ?

**I'm using fragments and JetPack navigation.**

Comment: You see the default button when the new Activity is showing? Maybe you are replacing it in the wrong place. Activity is being created, view is created, then half second after you replace the icon. 

Consider setting the activity view after you have changed that icon in the activity that you are going.

If you prefer, post full code and I could help you more.

Comment: @BogdanAndroid i'm using fragments and JetPack navigation.

Comment: So, you are replacing the icon on the activity?  or do you have a toolbar in each fragment?

Comment: @BogdanAndroid i have a toolbar in my activity (initialization and setting nav controller logic for it). In base fragment i have a logic to setting and handling this icon (depending on where i am now i'm setting to this icon to null (i don't want to see hamburger icon when i'm in parent)). Maybe this is a not appropriate place to having such code or it is ok ?

Comment: Are you setting your navigationIcon in the navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Navigation Components, the expected behavior is the Up button displayed when you are on a non-root destination.
You can change it using the `addOnDestinationChangedListener` after your setup method.

Something like:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.xxxx) {
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx)
   } else {
       //
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between setting navigation icon in this place and the place, where i'm setting ? (onViewCreated)

Comment: @kxko The difference is that you are using the Navigation components which works under your code and sets the icon for you.

Comment: Hm, thanks, i will try it and will let you know ! Could you please give me link that information ? Because i didn't find it at android.developer (or maybe i'm blind :) ) Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can check https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration. In particular *"When the user is on any other destination, the Navigation button appears as an Up button"*

Comment: Why do we have to change it all the time fragment is changed? Can't we just override Menu, Back button somehow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812362/how-to-set-my-own-menu-and-back-icons-for-toolbar Because in your case you would need to know which fragment is root or for navigation bottom or non-root. Navigation Component handles this logic by itself

Comment: What is xxx can you please explain?

Comment: @MdImranChoudhury The resource ID of destination.