# How to set my own Menu and Back icons for Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I use Navigation Component which automatically handles if app should display Menu button to display to open navigation drawer or Back button to return back to home (dashboard for example):

```
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    binding.navigationDrawer.setupWithNavController(navController)
    binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

and   `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, bundle -> ... }`

So it can be

[image]

or

[image]

Navigation Component automatically sets those icons.

How can I override each icon? I need to override Menu and Back buttons icon.

Please don't mention methods which only set one icon...

Comment: Do you want to change the icon type i.e. the burger/back arrow?

Comment: @Zain yes, but not in `addOnDestinationChangedListener`

Answer (score 2):

> Navigation Component automatically sets those icons.
>
> How can I override each icon? I need to override Menu and Back buttons icon.

So, now you can navigate between the fragments, upon that you removed the fragment that you want to show the back/up button from the top hierarchy of the `AppBarConfiguration`.

Assuming you've 3 fragments: home, gallery, and slideshow; and you wish to show the back button on the gallery fragment, and the normal menu button in others.

So, you'd have something like:

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_slideshow
    ), drawerLayout
)

setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Now we need to change the icons without using `addOnDestinationChangedListener`.

The icon can be changed with `supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawableRes)`

But, actually icons need to be changed manually as this is not the default behavior of the drawer layout, and navigation components has no idea about that; so you can do that using the APIs of the drawer layout.

So, first register a listener to this icon with `binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)` and this requires to create the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, so save it locally in the activity, and the rest is in the code comments:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Intialization code is omitted....
        
        toggle = getActionBarDrawerToggle(binding.drawerLayout, binding.appBarMain.toolbar).apply {
            setToolbarNavigationClickListener {
                // Back to home fragment for any hit to the back button
                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home)
            }
            // Intialize the icon at the app start
            enableHomeBackIcon(false)
        }
    }

    fun enableHomeBackIcon(enabled: Boolean) {
        // Enable/Disable opening the drawer from the start side
        toggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = !enabled
       
        // Change the default burger icon
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(
            if (enabled) R.drawable.back_arrow
            else R.drawable.burger
        )
    }

    private fun getActionBarDrawerToggle(
        drawerLayout: DrawerLayout,
        toolbar: Toolbar
    ): ActionBarDrawerToggle {
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.open,
            R.string.close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle!!)
        toggle?.syncState()
        return toggle as ActionBarDrawerToggle
    }

}
```

And as per your requirement, instead of using `addOnDestinationChangedListener`, you can utilize the drawer fragments lifecycle method; I will be using `onViewCreated()`:

Home & Slideshow fragment: Disable the back button through the activity:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).enableHomeBackIcon(false)
}
```

Gallery fragment: Enable the back button through the activity:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).enableHomeBackIcon(true)
}
```

Comment: I have the pretty much the same situation but i have only bottomNavigation without drawer and i can't set AppBar back icon. I've tried via `supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator ` but icon is not setted. How i can set back icon in this situation?